# Data Frame transpose and bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data = {'Country' : 'UK',
        '2011': 388416,
        '2012': 386257,
        '2013': 369576
        }
dd = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country','2011', '2012', '2013'], index=['1'])
```

[image]

When I try to create a bar chart, I get this result:

```
dd.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is a simple bar chart that shows the years as X and the values on Y-Axis.

I tried to switch the rows and columns using transpose:

```
ddf=dd.transpose()
ddf
```

[image]

But this won't generate any graph as the data frame has no columns.

Would anyone be able to suggest:

1. How do I create a graph from data frame 'dd'?
2. How do I add columns to data frame ddf?

I will appreciate the support!

Comment: `dd.set_index("Country").T.plot(kind='bar')` ?

Comment: `dd.set_index('Country').T.plot.bar()`

Comment: @anky and Scott Boston. Thank you. It worked. Why did we have to set_index on 'Country'? I looked up the 'T.plot' and I understood that by default 'DataFrame.plot' plots with the rows as the X-axis and T.plot plots columns on the X-axis instead? Thank you again.

Comment: transpose swaps the row and column indexes.  If you don't define the index it will use the default row index which is the row number

Comment: @Adrian That is because the Country is currently a column and not an index, and for getting it as index we need to set it as index and then transpose

Comment: @RobRaymond, anky and Scott, thank you. Very helpful!